# Fastest way to import data from one database to other in mysql using Java

Tags: java, mysql, performance, import, export-to-csv

DBMS - mysql

Language - Java

I have two databases

**Database One - I  have only SELECT access.**

Database Two - Complete access.

**Exact Requirement : -**

I have to import many TABLES from Database One to Database Two.

**Current Solution :-**

1. I am SELECTING all rows from table and storing result in ResultSet.

   ```
   String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName +" ;";
   Result Set res = runSql(sql);
   ```
2. Write each row from the ResultSet into a CSV file.

   ```
   OutputStreamWriter writer = null;
   writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName), "UTF-8");

   while (res.next() ){
               for (int j = 1; j <= noOfColumns.size(); j++) {
                   if(j != 1)
                       writer.append(",");
                   writer.append("\""+res.getString(j)+"\"");
               }

               writer.append("\n");
           }
   ```
3. Use LOAD DATA INFILE to fill database Two from CSV file.

   ```
   String sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '"+fileName+"' INTO TABLE "+tableName+ " CHARACTER SET UTF8 "+"     COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY \"\n\";";
   return runSql(sql);
   ```
4. Repeating this process for all tables.

**My Question :-**

Can I do better as some tables have more than millions of rows?
I find out that most of time is used by step 2 ( ResultSet to CSV writing ).

Comment: Are the databases on the same server by chance?

Comment: No, databases are on different servers. And I don't know much about database One. I do not have any control over database One.

Comment: Can't you export-import functionality. Instead of reading from DB1 and then writing to a file, directly export data from DB1 into a file and import data in DB2. This will save file writing and iterating over result set.

Comment: @NachiketKate Could you please explain your point? I am a beginner only. And I also can't write any file in DB1 server.

Comment: Every database has facility to export large tables/data into a file called export operation. File format are available as csv,custom delimiter etc. and for importing same exported data also. This facility is provided by DB thus it is generally works faster than manual query fetching-iterating over result set-writing to a file-then inserting to a DB. I hope you understand now.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem is that you should be using a `BufferedWriter,` but more to the point you should be creating the file at the server with `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`, not by iterating over a `ResultSet` or loading from a client-side file.

In fact why Java? The fastest way is not to use Java at all, but the MySQL Workbench, HeidiSQL, etc., and just import an SQL dump.

Comment: But don't you think I need FILE [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file) permissions at the Database One server ( which I don't have ) for OUTFILE ? [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html)

Comment: @shiva Of course, but it the solution to a permissions problem isn't to write a whole lot of inefficient and troublesome code. It is to execute the required commands as a user who has the required permissions.